# How do I prevent my router from resetting when many clients are present?

Tags: router

When few devices are connected to my router, nothing happens. However, when more than 10 devices are connected, the router resets itself or I have to reset it myself.

Is this a problem with the router itself or is there some setting I need to configure to allow more devices on the router?

Comment: What is the make and model of your router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration you're talking about most likely doesn't exist.

Hardware restarting itself is usually because of:

- Bad drivers.
- Heat issues.

You could try:

- Updating firmware.
- Cooling the router in some way.

Comment: have placed it on a point higher than the table sureface and have updated the firmware - will give it a day and get back.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue - when my PC was on, all worked, but when I had multiple peripherals it failed. It was almost as if the router just couldn't handle it all.

It turned out to be that - the router was cheap and couldn't deal with something (maybe the amount of traffic / dealing with the DHCP / etc).

Therefore, on top of TFM's good suggestions, can you try a different router because quite frankly if the router isn't up to it, then nothing will help other than a replacement.

Comment: I agree with Dave. Firmwares are not updated as soon often as one should expect, and handling the cooling issues is not practical. A router should have decent cooling, as you are not supposed to attach a CPU cooler to it.

Comment: the router was on my table which was heating up quite a lot. Have kept it slightly higher than the surface with some makeshift stands. lets see if this helps. If it doesn't, I will look into the firmware and getting a new router.

Comment: @ArvindSridharan - I agree, follow TFM's suggestion first (mostly because they're quick and easy to implement and free!)

Comment: have updated the firmware - will give it a day and get back.

Comment: @DaveRook - done!